# Null values when I do a post request H2 datbase springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

I am trying to make a springboot project, but I came across a problem I do not understand. I am using the H2 database, for storing some data, when i do the post request with postman the data being sent to the database has null values, so I am saving a user with name and email. both name and email are null.

This is my entity class, I have 2 constructors, since it does not let me not have the default one, but it seems that it just jumps to the default even when i give a json body?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users") // Specify the table name

public class User {
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Long id;
 private String username;
 private String email;

public User(String username, String email) {
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
}

public User() {
}
```

The controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
 public class UserController {
 ....
   @PostMapping
   public User createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
    System.out.println("Received Request Body: " + user.getUsername());
    return userService.createUser(user);
   }
```

code from the service

```
public User createUser(User user) {
    return userRepository.save(user);
}
```

the repo just extends extends JpaRepository<User, Long> { }

The result from H2 when i send this post

```
{
"username": "john_doe",
"email": "john@example.com" }
```

[image]

Comment: You should add setters to the User class. They are needed for JSON deserialization. (JPA don't need getters/setters but Jackson does)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add getters and setters to your entity class like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String username;
    private String email;

    public User(String username, String email) {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public User() {
    }
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Or just use `lombok` to avoid all of this code. You can learn about it [HERE](https://www.baeldung.com/intro-to-project-lombok).